# What programming conventions are often taught but are currently outdated in modern software development?

Tags: conventions

An example could be mutators (getters and setters) because they break OOP encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

Mandatory brackets in **If statements**, they are unnecessary in a fail fast pattern when you try to verify and exit your method with a single line return statement ASAP.